# jQuery Mobile split-view like on their demo

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to accomplish the split-view layout that jQuery Mobile uses in their own demo on http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/intro.html. I tried copying their source code (everything within body), but all i get is a top to bottom layout where the menu is in a collapsable section. How do i accomplish this split-view? Is it called something else, since i don't find anything on jQuery Mobiles own page about it?

Comment: What device are you testing this on? phones are going to stack the views but tablets will show the split view. Also could you provide some example code or a http:jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I am testing this on desktop. Fiddle is coming up

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gildebrand/YAeD4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have done it using some basic css width and a float attribute

In your css you can add

```
 .content-primary{width:60%;float:right;padding:0.6em 0%;}
 .content-secondary{width:30%}
```

​This will give a split view.
Hope this helps..